# How do I convert a table to long format?

Tags: r

| field | Fund1 | Fund2 | Fund3 | Fund4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Subdetail | Test | Test2 | Test3 | Test 4 |
| Amount | 500 | 520 | 100 | 400 |
| Percentage Limit | 30 | 20 | 20 | 100 |

So I have the above test table named data1. I wish to convert it to something like below:

| Name | field | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fund1 | Subdetail | Test |
| Fund1 | Amount | 500 |
| Fund1 | Percentage Limit | 30 |

How should I do this? I tried:

```
data1 <- reshape2::melt(data1, idvar = 'field')
```

But it does not work

Comment: ``dat %>% pivot_longer(-field)``

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)     

df <- read.csv(text = "field    Fund1   Fund2   Fund3   Fund4
Subdetail   Test    Test2   Test3   Test 4
Amount  500 520 100 400
Percentage Limit    30  20  20  100", sep = '\t')

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Fund1:Fund4, names_to = "Name", values_to = "Value")
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   field            Name  Value 
   <chr>            <chr> <chr> 
 1 Subdetail        Fund1 Test  
 2 Subdetail        Fund2 Test2 
 3 Subdetail        Fund3 Test3 
 4 Subdetail        Fund4 Test 4
 5 Amount           Fund1 500   
 6 Amount           Fund2 520   
 7 Amount           Fund3 100   
 8 Amount           Fund4 400   
 9 Percentage Limit Fund1 30    
10 Percentage Limit Fund2 20    
11 Percentage Limit Fund3 20    
12 Percentage Limit Fund4 100
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to pivot_longer()? Can't seem to update tidyverse to the version that has it

Comment: Try `gather` it is doing the same thing

Comment: `pivot_longer()` isn't in `dplyr` its in `tidyr`

Comment: Right! I think it's best to install `tidyverse`

Comment: It might be best to install `tidyverse`, but I personally do not like loading the entire thing just for one function. Not saying it's wrong, but I would just be loading `tidyr` here. But as we can see, not always easy to remember what is where!